# Ubuntu 14.04 Unknown Display

Tags: xorg, display, resolution, system-settings, administration

I have installed **Ubuntu 14.04** in my machine(with Gigabyte motherboard), having an **Acer 19"** Monitor. Unfortunately its resolution not working properly. See the image.

[image]

This is my `xrandr -q` output.

[image]

But when I take system settings for adjusting display it shows unknown display and only two resolutions available on the drop down as given in the picture.

[image]

Please let me know if you need any input from my side.

Thanks in advance.

Please help me to correct the display resolution as I am a beginner to Linux and Ubuntu. This is my last 30 lines of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

[image]

The result of running `sudo lspci | grep VGA` is as follow.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Comment: please give us the output of `sudo lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: I think it's a problem with your graphics driver, not monitor. What's your video card model?

Comment: I don't have any graphics card installed on my system. Is there anything else you required from my side ? like any terminal command output ?

Comment: What kernel version are you using? [this comment makes me ask](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/comment/700#comment-700)

Comment: This is my kernal version - `3.13.0-30-generic`

Comment: Sorry, This is my kernel version - `3.13.0-36-generic`

Comment: Any updates from anyone ?

Comment: @UvaisIbrahim I do have the same issue. Did you get a perfect solution??

Answer (score 2):

I found this on the Arch Distro BBS maybe it can help: 
[Intel HD Graphics 4600 driver works as Intel Xeon E3-1200](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1329727#p1329727)

You might try installing the Intel-microcode package as well.  You are most likely utilizing the Intel Processor's GPU, without knowing what model Mother Board you have.

Comment: sudo apt-get install intel-microcode && sudo reboot helped me.

Answer (score 1):

This might help someone.

Try a better VGA cable.

A poor quality VGA cable often causes this kind of problem. I've recently stumbled upon this strange problem and couldn't able to find a reasonable cause for this issue in Ubuntu (In 16.04.2 for me).

Cable type which worked for me : HOTRON E246588 AWM style 20276 VW-1 80°C 30V

Comment: Thank you for this response. I ran into this problem. I was in the settings for 20 minutes and entered a few things in the command line. I began to think I needed a new monitor. Then I read this and found the connection to the VGA extension cable was just barely hanging on. Plugged it in properly and "bingo!" problem solved. Thank You!

Comment: @OnePuttMike I am glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating and upgrading your system `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Also try going to Software and Updates -> Additional Drivers and changing the display driver.

Comment: Yes. I have already ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. But didn't help. Also there is no any software updates for this time.

Comment: What dies Additional Drivers show?

Comment: It says `No additional drivers available`.

Comment: Does your login screen look the same way?

Comment: Yes. Login screen also looks the same way.

Comment: Did you chose the option to install updates upon installation?

Answer (score 0):

just going to Software and Updates then additional drivers and change the driver by chose the most recent and stable one.

Comment: On Software and Updates, in additional drivers tab, it says `No additional drivers available`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [solution](http://my.oschina.net/eechen/blog/227134).

Use `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-settings nvidia-prime` and then reboot. You can use application named nvidia x server to configure the display.